# Exclude devices that do not support multitasking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I'm making an app that requires multitasking. Is there a way to compile an iPhone/iPad (universal) app so it excludes devices that do not support multitasking. I know iPhone 1, iPhone 3G and iTouch 1-2 do not support multitasking but I haven't found a way to build my app so it prevents people to download the app from the app store if they have one of these devices.

I was thinking to simply set the "Architectures" setting to armv7 on Xcode but I'm not sure if this will work and if it will have any other consequences.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should [check in your application for multitasking support](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW11) and fall back to a non multitasking alternative if it is not available.

Suppose you change the supported architectures to include ARM7 upwards.  If you do, you need to find out what happens if somebody attempts to deploy such an application to an incompatible device.  If iTunes stops them from doing it, that's fine and it's the right answer.  But if iTunes lets them do deploy the app and it crashes when they try to run it, it would be far better to do the test for multitasking support and display an alert telling the user why your app won't work.

Comment: The problem is that the app I'm creating is basically not useful if you don't have multitasking support so falling back to a non multitasking alternative is not really an option. What do you think about just setting the valid architecture to armv7, how would that look on the app store? would it require to have an armv7 device to download it?

Comment: @Enrique R. I'm curious as to what task *requires* multi tasking support.  See answer edit for further thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When reading the docs about the "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" it looks like I can set a key to require 'armv7', this will prevent people to install the app on a armv6 device - From the docs: "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an application requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing applications on a device that does not support the listed capabilities."

Comment: I think I will submit with the armv7 requirement on the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key and see what happens. I will post my results here once my app goes through the review process.

Comment: The only worry (besides the possibility of being rejected on review) is if the user downloads the app through the **desktop iTunes**, and **THEN** tries to sync it to the device. They will be very disappointed and/or feel deceived, specially if the app is paid.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the minimum API level supported to be iOS 4.3. This version only runs on devices that support multi-tasking.

Comment: Hi. The problem with this is that there are still many devices (iphone 4 and ipads) that are still running iOS 4.2 and that can handle multitasking. If I set the API level to iOS4.3 would I be excluding all the devices that are still running 4.2 but that are capable of multitasking?

Answer (score 0):

Go to targets section of your project--> navigate to Build Tab-->Go to Deployment tab & select IOS deployment target as 4.2. It will not run on IOS versions earlier than this.

[image]

Comment: iOS 4 can run on an iPhone 3G, which does not support multitasking. So setting a minimum iOS version is not sufficient.

Comment: @Mike Apple supported the 3G for early releases in the 4.x series but more recent versions are 3GS and above. I thought it was in 4.3 -- see my answer -- but the principle of using the deployment target is sufficient. The trick is getting the right version.