# Restrict installation to multitasking-capable devices?

Tags: ios, plist, multitasking

Is there a way to restrict the installation of my app to allow only multitasking-capable devices?

My app needs to do some background task (finish a download in the background when minimized).
I could work around it (abort the task and start over next time), but that would add complexity (and bugs), and I can do without supporting the iPhone 3G/equivalent iPod Touch.

The .plist file lets you set required device capabilities (OpenGL ES 2.0, etc.), but multitasking is nowhere to be found.

I could set the minimum deployment target to iOS 4.3, but I don't want to miss on iPhone 3GS/iPhone 4 users who aren't savvy enough to upgrade their OS and might still be on 4.2 or less.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT: I found this discussion
[Exclude devices that do not support multitasking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491728/exclude-devices-that-do-not-support-multitasking)

...So it seems the best way is to limit support to only armv7 CPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested on my own edit, it seems that **there is no 'required device capability' that corresponds exactly to multitasking-capable devices**.

However, these very same devices just happen to be exactly the same ones that support OpenGL ES 2.0, and *that* is in the list of  device capabilities you can specify in your Info.plist file. But this is at most a (perfect) work-around.

The correct thing to do would be to set a deployment target of 4.3, since only multitasking-capable devices can run that OS. However, it is possible that some multitasking-capable device might still be running iOS 4.2 or less. This is less of a concern as iOS 4 becomes older: in the verge of the iOS 6 release, a few months from now, dropping support for iOS 4.x altogether is a more viable option.